# Access a variable outside the method in objective-c

Tags: ios, nsarray, global-variables

I have this function that is storing the contents of an array in three different variables. My question is how can I access to the contents stored in _company.address from another function in the same class.

```
-(NSArray *) csvArray2CompaniesArray:(NSArray *) csvArray
{
    int i=0;    

    NSMutableArray *ma = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSArray * row in csvArray)
    {
        if (i>0)
        {
            Company *_company = [[Company alloc] init];

            _company.name = [row objectAtIndex:0];
            _company.address = [row objectAtIndex:1];
            _company.telephone = [row objectAtIndex:2];

            [ma addObject:_company];
        }
        i++;
    }
    return (NSArray *) ma;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague, so I'm unsure if you'd like to know how to pass the address as a parameter into another function or if the function you just entered isn't compiling due to `_company.address` not being available.

Comment: The function compiles with no problem. I just wanted to know how to access the contents stored in _company.name from another function or method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot the accessibility of an object is private in a function.Either you declare it as global or declare it in class's scope.Better in .h file

You can use the functios value as  :-

```
YourViewControllerWithFunction *accessFunc=[[YourViewControllerWithFunction  alloc]]init];

Company *_company=[accessFunc csvArray2CompaniesArray:youInputArray];

[_company objectAtIndex:intVallue];//Use in loop
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply.
I have no problem accessing to the data through a UITableView initializing with

Company *p = (Company *)[self.importedRows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Is there any similar way to initialize it? For example in a "-(void) viewDidLoad"?

Comment: you might have been accessing the object in same function or block that's why.initializing a variable in either viewDidLoad or init method that has usage in multiple funtions or procedures.

Comment: Do you want to send a data generated in a class to another class?

Comment: Yes, just want to access the data generated outside the function. Sorry if I don't explain myself well. I'm new in this.

Comment: but you have given a parameter to function as nsarray and it will change your data everytime you access..Anyways to access in forward classes you can simply create property or use NSUserDefaults to access over entire application ..To get result at certain instant like parsing completion or backward references you will have to use delegate..protocol

Comment: I just checked and your code worked just fine. Just what I needed.thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You should correct the return value of your function to `NSMutableArray` or make a `copy` to get the `NSArray` of the `NSMutableArray` you created.

After that, you can access the contents of your array from anywhere inside your class like:

```
for (Company *c in [self csvArray2CompaniesArray:csvarray])
{
    NSLog(@"%@", c.address);
}
```